# How to export microphone recorded byearray as wav or mp3 from flash actionscript to php

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-3, flash-builder

I need help in exporting a bytearray to a wav or mp3 (or anything that runs!) from my flash code to my php page.

I am using microphone recorder to record voice, i use a a url request to send my ByteArray to my PHP page.

i send the bye array from flash like this:

var url = "http://localhost/wordswesay/uploads/testrec.php";
                var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader ("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");
                var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);

```
            request.requestHeaders.push (header);
            request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

            request.data = soundBytes; //FLV byteArray  
            var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

            trace(request.data);
            loader.load(request)
```

and in my php file, i do the following:

```
<?php

echo "test";

  $im =  $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"];
    $fp = fopen("test.wav", 'w');    
    fwrite($fp, $im);
    fclose($fp);

?>
```

at the server side (the sime file as the php script) i get the test.wav with about 200kb of size but i can not play it! media players says it can't play this file as the codec might not be supported.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more to a audio file than the audio bytes, there needs to be a format specific header, and the bytes need to be stored in a way specific to the format type, which is often (mp3s for example) different then the raw bytes Flash will be giving you (which are decoded already)

Take a look on Google for a audio encoder, either in AS3 or PHP that will convert your bytes to a mp3 file, I'm sure there is something, but I don't know one off hand. Hopefully that explains why its not working, and pushes you into the right direction. Goodluck!